# Local banach algebra without zero divisors

Tags: functional-analysis, ideals, banach-algebras

I need to construct example of banach algebra with unique nontrivial maximal ideal and without zero divisors. I think it is must be a subalgebra of $\mathbb{C}[[z]]$, but I could not build anything.

Comment: I found https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~banalg20/Talks/kania1.pdf

Comment: That algeber have not zero divisors? It is not obvously for me.

Comment: Oh, I don't know! I just found that link and maybe you can find a (non maximal) prime ideal in that algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A = \mathbb{C}[[t]]$ be the algebra of formal series. Let $B \subset A$ be some subalgebra, satisfying $$\| a \| = \sum{a_{n} |w_{n}|} < \infty$$ Here $w_{n}$ is a sequence of positive numbers that we actually need to find.

First, note that $B$ is indeed local, since the set of all non-invertivle elements of $A$ is an ideal. (**update: why???**)

How to find $w_{n}$?

Since the $A$ is a Banach algebra, then $$||ab|| \leq ||a||||b||$$ so by comparing term-by-term coefficients one can extract the desired values.

**update**: if one takes $w_{n} = (1, 1, \frac{1}{2!}, \ldots, \frac{1}{n!}, \ldots, )$, then the property above holds and, moreover, it looks as if the subalgebra is indeed local but i can't see a fast way to recover it.

Comment: In fact, as i figured out -- it is a crucial step to check that the subalgebra is indeed local, which was not pointed out in this answer.